# How to pass custom data type to cucumber-jvm stepdef in latest 4.x version

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have recently upgraded to latest 4.x version of cucumber-jvm in my project in order to leverage parallel execution feature of cucumber. But I am facing this issue now with respect to having custom data type as parameter. Earlier we had an interface called `Transformer` which we can implement for custom data types, now in the latest version I've found `TypeRegistryConfigurer` interface which needs to be implemented. But it is not recognising the step as I would've expected. Details as follows:

Gherkin Step:

```
Given user gets random(3,true,true) parameter
```

StepDefinition:

```
@Given("user gets {random} parameter")
public void paramTest(RandomString randomString) {
    System.out.println(randomString.string); 
}
```

RandomString class:

```
public class RandomString {

public String string;

public RandomString(String string) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("random\\((.?)\\)").matcher(string);
    String t = "";
    while (m.find()) {
        t = m.group(1);
    }
    boolean isAlpha = true, isNum = true;
    if (t.length() > 0) {
        String[] placeholders = t.split(",");
        if (placeholders.length == 3) {
            int count = Integer.parseInt(placeholders[0]);
            isAlpha = Boolean.valueOf(placeholders[1]);
            isNum = Boolean.valueOf(placeholders[2]);
            this.string = string.replaceAll("random(.*)", RandomStringUtils.random(count, isAlpha, isNum));
        }
    }
    this.string = string.replaceAll("random(.*)", RandomStringUtils.random(3, isAlpha, isNum));
}
}
```

TypeRegistryImpl:

```
public class TypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
                "random",
                "random([0-9],true|false,true|false)",
                RandomString.class,
                RandomString::new)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution after trial and hit and going through some examples from some Unit Tests in cucumber-jvm project.

Modified **StepDef**:

```
@Given("user gets {random} parameter")
public void paramTest(String randomString) {
    System.out.println(randomString.string); 
}
```

TypeRegistryConfigurer Implementation:

```
import cucumber.api.TypeRegistry;
import cucumber.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer;
import io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CaptureGroupTransformer;
import io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.ParameterType;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import java.util.Locale;

public class TypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
                "random",
                "random\\(([0-9]+),(true|false),(true|false)\\)",
                String.class,
                new CaptureGroupTransformer<>() {
                    @Override
                    public String transform(String[] args) {
                        return RandomStringUtils.random(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Boolean.valueOf(args[1]), Boolean.valueOf(args[2]));
                    }
                })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string `random(3,true,true)` does not match the pattern used in:

```
typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
        "random",
        "random([0-9],true|false,true|false)", 
        RandomString.class,
        RandomString::new)
);
```

You can verify this by creating the pattern and testing it:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("random([0-9],true|false,true|false)");
        // prints out false
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("random(3,true,true)").matches());
    }
}
```

You have also not used a matching pattern in `RandomString`.

Comment: Thanks mpkorstanje for pointing out that my Regex was wrong. I've found the correct regex for my string and also found the correct way of implementing TypeRegistryConfigurer.